# PointXYZ python usage question

Tags: python

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to include PointXYZ in a python pgm. But it is unable to locate PointXYZ. If I include the *import pcl* it say it can not find module pcl.  Is there a install I am missing or is there no python wrapper for it?

```
         self.subPoseWithCovar = rospy.Subscriber("/depth/points", PointXYZ, self.callback)
         self.tf_pub = rospy.Publisher("/depth/points2", PointXYZ, queue_size=10)
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/205796/pointxyz-python-usage-question/) by [rnunziata](https://answers.ros.org/users/5119/rnunziata/) on ROS Answers with karma: 713 on 2015-03-24

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

What exactly are you trying to subscribe to? `/depth/points` is probably going to be a message of type
[sensor_msgs/PointCloud2](http://docs.ros.org/api/sensor_msgs/html/msg/PointCloud2.html). There are no official PCL bindings for python, so you will need to use something like [sensor_msgs/point_cloud2.py](https://github.com/ros/common_msgs/blob/jade-devel/sensor_msgs/src/sensor_msgs/point_cloud2.py) to convert the data to a usable format.

---

Originally posted by [Dan Lazewatsky](https://answers.ros.org/users/173/dan-lazewatsky/) with karma: 9115 on 2015-03-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [rnunziata](https://answers.ros.org/users/5119/rnunziata/) on 2015-03-24**:
I wanted to translate a pointcloud2 into another frame. There is a method in c++ method transformPointCloud is there a similar python method you know of.

**Comment by [Dan Lazewatsky](https://answers.ros.org/users/173/dan-lazewatsky/) on 2015-03-25**:
If all you want the node to do is transform the point cloud from one frame to another, it will be very slow in python (you'd have to transform each point individually). However, you can use a [PassThrough filter](http://wiki.ros.org/pcl_ros/Filters#PassThrough) and set the output_frame.

**Comment by [rnunziata](https://answers.ros.org/users/5119/rnunziata/) on 2015-03-25**:
Seeing the PointXYZ I take it PassThrough filters are not in Python. I will write the cpp pgm.

**Comment by [Dan Lazewatsky](https://answers.ros.org/users/173/dan-lazewatsky/) on 2015-03-25**:
The PassThrough filter isn't in python, but using it doesn't require writing any code at all, just configuring it in a launch file.

**Comment by [rnunziata](https://answers.ros.org/users/5119/rnunziata/) on 2015-03-25**:
cool...thanks